# #1074 - Column length too big for column 'blackmails_made' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead

Tags: mysql

I am Installing a Browsergame but when the Script connects to my Database this is the error i get how can i fix this with my mysql?

> #1074 - Column length too big for column 'blackmails_made' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead

thank you for all youre help.

if this helps here is my mysql settings

```
Language Options    asp_tags    Allow ASP-style <% %> tags.     Off
File Uploads    file_uploads    Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.     On
Paths and Directories   include_path    Windows: "\path1;\path2" c:\php\includes"   .:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php
Resource Limits     max_execution_time      30
Resource Limits     max_input_time      60
Resource Limits     memory_limit        256M
Data Handling   register_globals    You should do your best to write your scripts so that they do not require register_globals to be on; Using form variables as globals can easily lead to possible security problems, if the    code is not very well thought of.     Off
Language Options    safe_mode       Off
File Uploads    upload_max_filesize     Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.    2048M
```

Comment: Exception and settings format